# ETL : Flatten a nested array in an AWS glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, flatten

I am currently trying to import data stored in json using AWS Glue. 
The jsons contains an attribute 'tags' defined as an array of string. I have already imported the table without the tags at first place. I would like to be able to import the tag's attribute into another table in order to have a clean one-to-many relationship. After looking in the documentation, I can't see how to do that using the awsglue framework. Any ideas?

Hugo

Comment: Not answering your question but you'll probably need many-to-many (and a join table) unless tags never repeat across records or you don't care about redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Use relationize method in glue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html

There is example on github AWS too.